# Amazon API create a website

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I need to create website using Amazon API where I can pass static content(basically index.html content) and they should return some kind of temporary(internal?) URL to access newly created website.

What are the right services that need to be used to achive such goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is probably what you're looking for. It will host static content and if you expose the bucket as publicly visible, then you will get what you're looking for. Here is the developer guide for AWS PHP SDK with S3:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html

The bucket can be configured for website access via the putBucketWebsite() function.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketWebsite

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for

Comment: However I faced several issues:

1) By default it sets Content-Type: binary/octet-stream but I need simple text/html. From Managment console I can do that but from API it didn`t set it correctly. Is there a way to handle that!?

2) From the very same Managment console it is possible to set Bucket as Static Website. However didn`t find a way to do it from API as neither how to retrieve Bucket Static Website URL. Any ideas!?

Comment: Yes, I believe you want to use the putBucketWebsite() to set the configuration. To get the configuration you can use getBucketWebsite()  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putBucketWebsite

Comment: But still - none of those methods exposes endpoint like it`s shown in Managment Console "Endpoint: test-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: According to the documentation, your ARN will always be in the format: <!-- Amazon S3 bucket (and all objects in it)-->
arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/*  Look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Comment: I believe getBucketPolicy will return the policy and the arn is in there as 'resource'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43191/discussion-between-werd-and-user602525)